# How do I make more building "combos"?

Tags: happy-street

Early in the game I got a combo by following a specific recipe of placing buildings next to each other: Eye Glasses store, Fruit Stand, Flower Cart.  This created some huge windmill thing on top of the fruit stand, and apparently I get bonuses to the shops for arranging them this way.  Is there a generic formula, or some other way I can determine how to arrange buildings to get these bonuses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [here](http://www.chaptercheats.com/qna/iphone-ipod/110209/Happy-Street-Answers.htm?qid=24286):

> Combos are always made of two shops and a decoration, and they usually follow the theme of a particular kind of house. If you want to see all of them which are available, browse the decorations: the comments under them tell what two shops the decoration makes a combo with. If you don't see any more, it may mean you need to level up a little to unlock some new ones.

Note that in some cases, you will also need to upgrade a building a few times to be able to make a combo with it.